# Adding JavaScript at the bottom of a view using cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code

```
$this->addScript('<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("dsf");
            });
</script>');
```

Is it possible to add this at the bottom of my view? My reason being is it somehow always renders above the line where the jQuery library is included.

I've seen in the documentation they mention `$scripts_for_layout`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place your JS code at a precise place in your view, you can use

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock('$(document).ready(function() {
            alert("dsf");
        }');
```

But if you do want to have your JS code in the header (but after the jQuery inclusion), you can just continue to use `$this->addScript()`, but make sure to place the variable `$scripts_for_layout` *after* the call to `script()`:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
echo $scripts_for_layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<script>` tag for *jQuery* in the *header* (after the CSS).

Answer (score 1):

You also not use CakePHP's helper for this, just put `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` at the bottom of your view after all your html